# How to slow down javafx animation

Tags: animation, javafx

I'm trying to make the stage.show() slow down. I figured out I might need to set KeyFrame, but am stuck at KeyValue, not understanding T endValue or Interpolator interpolator. Is this the right approach? If so could anyone explain to me what type is T.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't slow `stage.show()` down, if `stage` is a JavaFX `Stage`, because this is not an animation.

Answer (score 1):

*Controlling Animation Speed*

An [animation's speed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#currentRateProperty) is primarily controlled by its [rate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#currentRateProperty).  Varying either the rate of playback of the animation or the duration of the animation will probably be all you need to do to get the animation speed you want.

```
animation.setRate(2) // play the animation at double speed.
animation.setRate(0.5) // play the animation at half speed.
```

*On Interpolation*

An interpolator is a mathematical function for calculating intermediate values between points.  Here is an article on [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

In JavaFX, the interpolators are used to define [easing functions](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html) for changing values between keyframes of an animation.  Likely, for what you are doing, either a straight linear interpolator or an ease in + ease out interpolator will be fine (those are the two most commonly used interpolators).  Most of the time, the default interpolator used by JavaFX suffices and you don't have to change it.

The apparent speed of an animation might also be effected by the interpolated easing function applied to the animation's key values or by the magnitude of a keyvalue change (e.g. number of pixels translated, number of times to scale) divided by the keyframe's duration.

*Further reference*

If you don't understand what this means, then read the [JavaFX animation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm) which will define the terms referenced and provide examples on how to use them.

*Additional items in your question*

What you want to do ("`stage.show()` slow down") is ambiguous to me in the context of animations, so I couldn't advise an approach for that - as TheJeed correctly states stage.show() is not an animation, so it makes no sense to try to apply animation to a stage.show() call.

`T` in the context of a KeyValue is a [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), which seems to answer the question in your question but not the question in your title.

Comment: My first negative score answer - that was deserved, I shouldn't have tried to answer this question as it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the question was poorly asked. I didn't have the right approach. Just simply changing thread.sleep() will do the work.

But thank you guys anyway!